# ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: oracle, listener

I've been working this issue all day, reading posts here and other locations.  I'm just not able to get past this error.  I can connect just fine locally on my server (CentOS), but continue to get the TNS:no listener error when trying to connect via my Mac (OSX Mavericks) which is on the same subnet.  Below are some notes I've captured based on what information I see that has been requested for this type of issue:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MISC NETWORK CONFIG:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@rubyrailssvr ~]# more /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.1.14   rubyrailssvr.homenet.com
[root@rubyrailssvr ~]#


[root@rubyrailssvr ~]# more /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=rubyrailssvr.homenet.com
[root@rubyrailssvr ~]#
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LISTENER.ORA File:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[oracle@rubyrailssvr ~]$ more /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.14)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
[oracle@rubyrailssvr ~]$
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TNSNAMES.ORA File:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[oracle@rubyrailssvr ~]$ more /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.14)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

[oracle@rubyrailssvr ~]$
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQLNET.ORA File:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
jfhogarty@rubyrailssvr:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin$ more sqlnet.ora
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (ALL)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES,ONAMES,HOSTNAME)
jfhogarty@rubyrailssvr:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin$
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CHECK LISTENERS:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[oracle@rubyrailssvr ~]$ lsnrctl

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 13-AUG-2014 17:56:21

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                13-AUG-2014 17:46:45
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 9 min. 39 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/rubyrailssvr/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.1.14)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=rubyrailssvr.homenet.com)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ON THE CLIENT:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
➜  ~  more /usr/local/oracle/admin/network/tnsnames.ora
rubyrailssvr =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.14)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = XE))
  )

rubyrailssvr.homenet.com =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.14)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = XE))
  )
➜  ~
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TRYING TO CONNECT:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
➜  ~  sqlplus system@rubyrailssvr

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Wed Aug 13 18:21:50 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener


Enter user-name: % 
➜  ~



➜  ~  sqlplus system@rubyrailssvr.homenet.com

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Wed Aug 13 18:22:17 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener


Enter user-name: 
➜  ~
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

First, thanks for the response.  I'm working on a Mac, and the instant client doesn't include the tnsping utility.  I had tried to login, from the remote computer, and that is where I got the TNS:no listener error.  Logging in on the server is fine.

I had tried the telnet test before, but as I did not have telnet installed and running on the server, that test was not helpful.  However, I decided to install telnet as it can be useful in testing.  While doing so, I noticed that a command I had executed at the command line to open a port to iptables was not there.  So I updated that file and now everything is working.

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/iptables

[BEFORE:]
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Jan 31 09:19:34 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6630:522769]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jan 31 09:19:34 2014

[AFTER:]
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Jan 31 09:19:34 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6630:522769]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jan 31 09:19:34 2014

service iptables restart
```

Chased my tail so much yesterday that I never thought to review the iptables file - /slap head!

Thank you,

John...
(HoGi)

Answer (score 2):

My sequence of steps for troubleshooting

1. Is the listener resolvable? `C:\>tnsping MYDB` (Confirms: the database listener is running on serverside)
2. Is there a firewall issue? `C:\>telnet hostname 1521`
3. Can I login? `C:\>sqlplus system/pass@MYDB` or `C:\>sqlplus system/pass@hostname:1521/MYDB` (Confirms: The database is open)
4. Finally, chances of having a successful login with your favorite dev-tool has increased by 100%

Answer (score 0):

In listener.ora file

set HOST=LOCALHOST

reason being that if your on a wireless network you can get assigned different ip addresses after every reboot which invalidates your listener settings if using a fixed ip address in your listener.ora file.

With HOST=LOCALHOST you are guaranteed consistency with regards the ip address settings between system reboots when it comes time that the listener service starts up.

Answer (score 0):

Its too late but I also face this problem currently and I solved this by.

1. Go to Net Manager(Oracle Net Manager) in your oracle installed
   system.
2. Expand Local > Listners > LISTNER.
3. Add new address protocol:TCP/IP, Host:YOURPCNAME.DOMAIN, Port:YOUR PORT.
4. Go to File > Save Network Configuration.
5. RESTART system.

below is snapshot for adding new address
[image]